# Name of provider for ODBC .Net?

Tags: .net, sql, odbc

I'm trying to configure a testing tool to use ODBC.Net to connect to a CA-Datacom database.

So I just downloaded & installed ODBC.Net. The testing tool wants a provider name, i.e. "MSDASQL" for Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Data Sources.

If I try to type in a provider name, such as "ADODB," I get an error saying that the provider isn't registered on the local machine.

Does anyone know what the appropriate provider name is for ODBC .Net?

Comment: Does the site from which you downloaded the ODBC connector not list the provider name?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21349768) explains that both system and user DSNs are created when the driver is installed. You therefore should be able to instantiate [`ODBCConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.aspx) with a [connection string that uses the DSN syntax](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn#p21).